# Visual Studios will not let me add multiple Text boxes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox

I am currently working on a small project for school. I have a search bar (made as a text box and a button) on my master page which is displayed across my content pages. I am at a point where I need 2 more text boxes to capture information but anytime I try to add one, it changes the ID of the existing text box, and does not add a new one. If I try to add another, it does the same thing. I even tried adding a form, and it still changes the ID of my search bar (text box), without adding anything new, and changes the value of my "Search" button to the text I put in the Submit button in my form. Is there any way to fix this issue, or am I just limited to one text box per page?

Brief bit from page I am currently working on.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CheckDates.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reservation1.CheckReservations" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="Mainpage.aspx">
        <input type="text" name="CheckInDate" value="Check in Date">
        <input type="text" name="CheckOutDate" value="CheckOutDate">
        <input onClick="window.location.href='Mainpage.aspx'" type="submit" value="Check Availibility">
        </form>
        </body>
</asp:Content>
```

Search bar bit from Master page

```
    <asp:Button ID="SiteSearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="SiteSearchButton_Click" />



<asp:TextBox ID="SiteSearchBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <a href="Mainpage.aspx" style="font-size:15px; color:white; padding-left:200px; padding-right:30px; padding-top:45px;
```

Comment: How are you trying to add new textbox? From designer or by changing code in aspx file?

Comment: I have tried both ways. Both continually have the same issue. Even when I placed the form in the code, it made the value from my second text box appear in the Search bar I created, and changed the button's text as well. I am using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Can you share the code of aspx and point out where you are trying to add textbox and what happens with some example?

Comment: I have added small bits from the page I am currently working on, and the bit containing the Search bar from the master page. Even in design mode if I drag a new text box into my page, it snaps to my text bar currently being used as my search bar, and changes the id on it. If I move that bar, it turns out I am actually moving my search bar, and it will no longer be located where it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you're referring to (styling or actual code), and it's been some time since I've worked with `WebForms`

Reminder: there is already one server side `form` that encloses *all* your `Content` pages in WebForms (it's defined in the Master page).

- So your first issue in the code above is that you are nesting `<forms>` (you can't). This isn't an "ASP.Net" thing, that's an [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element).
- Save time and go with WebForms conventions. Use [`Button.PostbackUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of html `input` fields that you're mixing in unnecessarily - not saying you *can't* but there's no reason to in your code above.
- Lastly, if you're relying on the Visual Studio `designer`, just **don't**. It's not a good WYSIWYG tool - never has, never will be. Visual Studio is primarily a developer tool - it *tries* to help with design, but well, doesn't really.

  Run your code in a browser and `View Source` to see the **rendered**
  output of all your code. You'll see the raw HTML that all your code ends up being - and should hopefully guide you to identifying what the problem really is.

Hth.

Comment: I agree with you, I am done using design mode completely. But honestly, I downloaded Visual Studio 2017, and the problem seemed to resolve itself. I have no idea what the actual underlying issue is.